# Display a YAML file in the UI using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a YAML file in the UI of my component using Reactjs.

```
 const ymlText = YAML.stringify({
      json1
    });
```

`ymlTxt` is my YAML file, I want it to display in UI.